# iOS localised push notifications with parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

in an iOS app we are sending push notifications.

using the "loc-key" in the alert we can show localized message in the banner that is displayed by iOS, in the language setup on the device.

can this localized message get parameters?

for example instead of showing
"You have new messages"

to show
"You have new messages from " where  will be a value sent with the message.

thanks.

Comment: sorry, RTM one more time and got the answer: use loc-args

Answer (score 0):

yes,

we can send push locally by excuting php file in terminal with command prompt,

following is a link , please follow this and you can get your answer ???

```
 $ cd ~/Desktop/
    Convert the .cer file into a .pem file:
    $ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem
    Convert the private key’s .p12 file into a .pem file:
    $ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12
    Enter Import Password: 
    MAC verified OK
    Enter PEM pass phrase: 
    Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

> You first need to enter the passphrase for the .p12 file so that
>   openssl can read it. Then you need to enter a new passphrase that will
>   be used to encrypt the PEM file. Again for this tutorial I used
>   “pushchat” as the PEM passphrase. You should choose something more
>   secure.
>       Note: if you don’t enter a PEM passphrase, openssl will not give an error message but the generated .pem file will not have the private
>   key in it.
>       Finally, combine the certificate and key into a single .pem file:

```
 $ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem

$ php simplepush.php
```

please follow the  below link, it would help you :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: thanks Arun, but i meant localised as in translated to the language of the app.